# Azure Functions Running AZ Commands

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-cli

I have a Powershell Script that contains az commands which i am running from an Azure Function

I have The module specified in requirements.psd1 and host json managed dependency is enabled

In my script I have put in the following commands

```
Get-Module -Name Az -ListAvailable
Import-Module Az
```

Get Module comes back as 4.8.0 is installed

I then get a warning

```
[Warning] The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'az' command definition. If this command belongs to a module available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency. If the module is installed but you are still getting this error, try to import the module explicitly by invoking Import-Module just before the command that produces the error: this will not fix the issue but will expose the root cause.
```

Followed by by actual command

```
az storage account keys list <blah>

[Error] ERROR: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: `az storage account keys list <blah>` that is an Azure CLI command, not an Azure Powershell

Comment: this would be the powershell cmd Get-AzStorageAccountKey https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageaccountkey?view=azps-5.5.0

Comment: But i have been able to run az commands in powershell on a windows machine with Azure CLI Installed?

Comment: Yes. But an azure function environment has little to do with your local PC setup

Comment: OK I digress now but this has thrown me in the past, is there some form of decision tree or something i can use to know what flavour of (similar) language to use in these scenarios?

Comment: not sure I understand your question? If you use Azure Functions with Powershell, just use the AZ-powershell module?! I has pretty much the same features as CLI, just different syntax etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> az cli is not available currently out the box in the functions
> powershell environment. This is a feature ask and we are looking into
> it.

Please refer to [GitHub Issue#221](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/221) for this.

*Using the corresponding `Azure PowerShell Modules` shall be the only way to go for now.*

*You can use [`Get-AzStorageAccountKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageaccountkey?view=azps-5.5.0) instead of `az storage account keys`*